# What's the difference between "mutilate" and "amputate"?

Tags: verbs, differences

I've searched about these words but didn't find a useful result. Here are definitions from Cambridge dictionary :

- Mutilate : to damage something severely, especially by violently removing a part
- Amputate : to cut off a part of the body

Please write the differences between these words .

Comment: Your own posted definitions explain the differences.

Comment: Amputation is usually positive (to save your life, for instance) whereas mutilation is negative (done for torture or the like). A doctor will amputate a leg, but probably a doctor doesn't mutilate you.

Comment: @Davo Can you explain more ? Because I can't understand differences from the definitions .

Comment: The comment below mine, by oerkelens, does a fine job.

Comment: Also, an amputation typically removes a body part that is *already damaged* and beyond repair.

Comment: If you botch an amputation you could mutilate someone.

Comment: Ehm, the word "amputate" is actually much more specific than simply "cut off part of the body". You cannot amputate someone by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mutilate**: To significantly damage or deminish structure, function and/or sensorium of a normal anatomical region, usually an appendage. Amputation, crushing trauma injury and serious burns are examples of mutilation.

**Amputation** (virtually always deliberate and performed by means of some type of blade) is the removal of an anatomical appendage. Limb, earlobe, eyelid and external genitalia are examples of appendages.

Answer (score 1):

Amputation is the removal of a limb. That is pretty complete mutilation or ruining of a limb as far as body's utility goes. The limb may still be unmutilated as it sits in the doctor's take-out bag.

To mutilate is to "mess up" the limb. To break, cut bruise or otherwise mangle the limb. If it stays attached it may heal in time but mutilate usually refers to permanent damage.

Comment: A surgeon might amputate a limb that has already been mutilated so badly that it is past saving.